# Как обрезать строку правильно на PHP?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Как правильно здесь обрезать строку так, чтобы получить только:

`2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_800.jpg`

а все остальное убрать из этой строки:

```
a:7:{i:800;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_800.jpg";i:500;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_500.jpg";i:300;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_300.jpg";i:295;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_295.jpg";i:75;s:39:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_75.jpg";i:40;s:39:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_40.jpg";i:0;s:36:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd.jpg";}
```

Comment: может выполнить unserialize и спокойно взять нужный элемент массива ?

Comment: это не массив, а строка

Comment: да, только это строка явно сделанная функцией serialize, по крайней мере по внешнему виду. И если это так то `unserialize()` сделает из нее опять ту структуру которую сериализовали

Comment: `это не массив, а строка` - оруууу!!!

Comment: Да, я угадал. http://ideone.com/Mflgfh

Answer (score 4):

Вам следует почитать о функции [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize).

Следующий код:

```
print_r(unserialize('a:7:{i:800;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_800.jpg";i:500;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_500.jpg";i:300;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_300.jpg";i:295;s:40:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_295.jpg";i:75;s:39:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_75.jpg";i:40;s:39:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_40.jpg";i:0;s:36:"2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd.jpg";}'));
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [800] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_800.jpg
    [500] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_500.jpg
    [300] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_300.jpg
    [295] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_295.jpg
    [75] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_75.jpg
    [40] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd_40.jpg
    [0] => 2a5cc72ffea060a4548ae03d6076f4bd.jpg
)
```

Нужная вам информация хранится в массиве под ключом `800`. Сохраните результат работы функции `unserialize` в переменную и работайте с ним.

Например так:

```
$images = unserialize('тут ваша строка');
print $images[800];
```